# Adding JSON files to .xcodeproj via python script?

Tags: python, ios, json, xcode

So basically, I have a python script that scrapes web data and stores it in JSON files. Now I want to add those JSON files to my Xcode project so I can display the data.

Right now my json files are stored in a folder. My first approach was to utilize a DB and use python to send those json files to the DB. For now it seems to sort of work, but these json files are intended to be updated daily.

My second approach was to just send those files from my python script to my Resources folder I made inside Xcode, however the files don't show up in the project.

Does anyone here that had experienced this can help me go in the right direction with this? Is there any flaws in my approach that I had missed?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Is the Xcode project going to be used to build an iOS app that's going to be using the data?

Comment: Yes you got it right. I have my json files, which gets updated with new info frequently, and I need to figure out how to send those files over to my Xcode project to display the data.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.